# What exactly is the difference between "to","on" and "via" in the missed approach icons section of Jeppesen charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, symbology, missed-approach

What exactly is the difference between "to", "on" and "via" in the Missed approach icons section of Jeppesen charts? Sometimes "on" is used and sometimes "to" is used. As for the "via", I have no idea. I know the meanings of the words, but I guess I can't understand why they are used differently because English is not my mother tongue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might help to also see the corresponding missed approach description texts here.

Comment: Yes, I tried to find it too, but unfortunately I couldn't find it.

Comment: You are absolutely right sir, I am uploading the charts of all 3 samples now.

Answer (score 2):

**Top one:**

"TO" means after climbing to 3000 ft on the missed approach track, then proceed **to** the VOR, the missed approach fix, and pick up the 051ᵒ radial outbound, which will almost certainly has a hold on that radial.

**Middle one:**

Climb to 2000 while flying ALONG the 044ᵒ radial of the CRL VOR. "ON" means you have to proceed along that particular track to maintain obstacle clearance.

**Bottom one:**

Go from TZK to ITZK while flying along the 111ᵒ radial of TZK while between those two waypoints, but how you get to TZK is up to you. "VIA" refers to a routing between specific waypoints as listed, where you just fly to the first one on your own using the most logical and direct routing.

You could say that the VIA instruction combines the TO instruction (find your way to the 1st waypoint) and the ON instruction (fly between waypoints on a specific track) into a single instruction.

In any case, the detailed instructions are in the MISSED APPROACH block near the top of the approach plate. Those blocks you are referencing are included below the vertical profile of the approach and are shorthand at-a-glance reminders of the key data of the missed approach.

Comment: Could you please share your source explaining this situation, sir?

Comment: It's just an english interpretation from somebody with an instrument rating. The missed approach block near the top of the approach plate explains it in plain english.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but after reviewing the charts, I think your definitions of "to" and "on" need to be swapped.

Comment: If you look at the chart I just added, according to your definition, the icons should be "to", not "on".  @John K

Comment: After reviewing the charts you posted I agree John's answer is spot on.  The differences in meaning between the "on" and "via" is negligible, and doesn't alter how you would fly the procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not agree. According to the charts, explanations and definitions were not enough for me. I don't understand the obvious difference. But I will ignore this part because it is a very unnecessary detail.

Comment: What does your instructor say?

Comment: What specific part of my comment, or John’s answer do you disagree with?  Do you think it makes a difference in how you would fly the missed approach?  If I were giving you directions to the muffin store and I said “follow Drury Lane…” or “go along…” or “proceed via… or “drive down…” does my choice of words affect how you get there?  I agree that standardized terminology is a good idea to reduce possible confusion, but this really isn’t one of those cases.

Comment: Not trying to argue here, you did acknowledge “it is a very unnecessary detail”, (which I agree with) I just feel incomplete if I can’t help someone understand something…